# Python - delete strings that are float numbers

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, floating-point

I have a file with lots of lines that contain numbers seperated by coma `,` on each line.

Some lines contain numbers that are `float numbers` ie: `['9.3']`

i have been trying to delete those numbers from the list for about 1h~ but no luck. and whenever it tries to use int on a float number it gives error. Im not sure how to remove these floating numbers from the lines

the numbers: https://pastebin.com/7vveTxjW

this is what i've done so far:

```
with open('planets.txt','r') as f:
    lst = []
    temp = []
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip()
        l = l.split(',')
        for x in l:
            if x == '':
                l[l.index(x)] = 0
            elif x == '\n' or x == '0':
                print "removed value", l[l.index(x)]
                del l[l.index(x)]

        try:
            temp.append([int(y) for y in l])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, modifying the list you are iterating over is a bad idea. A better idea might be to construct a new list from the elements that can be converted to an `int`.

```
def is_int(element):
    try:
        int(element)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

with open('planets.txt','r') as f:
    lst = []
    temp = []
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split(',')

        temp.append([int(y) for y in l if is_int(y)])
```

If you want to include the `float` values' integral component, you can do:

```
def is_float(element):
    try:
        float(element)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

with open('planets.txt','r') as f:
    lst = []
    temp = []
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split(',')

        temp.append([int(float(y)) for y in l if is_float(y)])
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like youre over complicating it, once you have got all your numbers from the file to a list just run this

```
numbers=["8","9","10.5","11.1"]
intList=[]
for num in numbers:
    try:
        int_test=int(num)
        intList.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

just change my numbers list to your list name

Answer (score 0):

When you get a list that contains digits (for instance, `['1','2.3','4.5','1.0']`) you can use the following

```
intDigits = [ i for i in digits if float(i) - int(float(i)) == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing int() on a float shouldn't give an error. Maybe your 'float' is actually a string as you're reading from the file, because

```
int('9.3')
```

doesn't work but

```
int(9.3)
```

does.

Edit:
How about applying this function to every number

```
def intify(n):
    if n == '':
        return n
    try:
        return int(n)
    except ValueError:
        return int(float(n))
```

Comment: That's why Im having trouble deleteing float numbers.

Comment: How about converting all numbers to float and then int?

Comment: Original numbers must be kept. Not allowed to convert to float then to int

Comment: You could write a small function like in my edit and pass every string you come across when you have a list, per line, of strings split by a comma

Answer (score 0):

You can just match digits followed by a point followed by more digits:

```
import re

output_list = []
input = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in input:
    if '.' not in line:
        output_list.append(line)
    else:
        output_list.append(re.sub(r"(\d+\.\d+)", '', line))
        print("Removed", re.search(r"(\d+\.\d+)", line).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the numbers as string and simply check if there is a 'dot' in each 'splitted item' to identify floats.

```
with open('planets.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = ','.join([item for item in line.strip().split(',') if not '.' in item])
        print(line)
        # ... write to file ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove floats this was the simplest method for me.

```
mixed = [1,float(1),2,3,4.3,5]

ints = [i for i in mixed if type(i) is not float]
```

Results in: [1, 2, 3, 5]